# Entity Framework with User Table Value Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2014

I have the following scenario:

- An entity called `Degree` that has a complex type `Period`
- I want to use the feature in sql `User-Defined Table type`

**The entities code**

```
public class Degree {
    public string Institution {get;set;}
    public string Major {get; set;}
    public Country Country {get; set;}
    public Period StartOn {get; set;}
    public Period EndOn {get; set;}    
}

public class Period {
    public int Year {get; set;}
    public int Month {get; set;}
    public bool IsPresent {get; set;}
}
```

**The DbContext code**

```
public class Context: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Degree> Degrees {get; set;}

    public override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Degree>()
                    .Property(t => t.StartOn).HasColumnType("udt_period");
    }
}
```

** Error **

> Error CS0453  The type 'Period' must be a non-nullable value type in
>   order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'StructuralTypeConfiguration.Property(Expression>)'

How to let the entity framework to create the user defined table type and to use `StartOn` and `EndOn` as `udt_period`

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a column in database table as **User-Defined Table Type**, usually its used as parameters for stored procedures.

You can define a **User-Defined Data Type** from the SQL server side as `varchar(8)` for example and you can use it in your solution.

The value of **StartOn** might be as `09/2014` or `Sep 2014` and the value of **EndOn** might be as `11/2015` or `Nov 2015` or `Present` , if you want to use `09/2014` format, then make the datatype as `varchar(7)` instead of `varchar(8)`

In order to apply the above recommendation, your code should be modified in the following way:

```
public class Degree {
    public string Institution {get;set;}
    public string Major {get; set;}
    public Country Country {get; set;}
    public string StartOn {get; set;}
    public string EndOn {get; set;}    
}
```

If you are using Code First approach, You can still create the user-defined data type from your application side if you are using **Migrations**, in the **Seed** method.

```
protected override void Seed(Context context)
{
    // create the type 
    var sql = "if type_id('udt_period') is null create type udt_period from varchar(8) not null";
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);

    // you can alter the table column type
    var alter = "alter table Degrees alter column {0} udt_period not null"
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format(alter,"StartOn"));
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format(alter,"EndOn"));
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible, EntityFramework can't map an object with 3 properties to a single column, you have to expand the 3 proprties into 3 columns in the database for the `StartOn` and `EndOn`

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you,but the other answer contains a  more  details and they were  very helpful.